# 'install-peerdeps' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file (windows 7)

Tags: node.js, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I’m trying to setup an ES6 starter project/template/workflow here and I’m trying to include Airbnb’s ESLint/javascript style guide. I currently have ESLint setup in the project.

I am on **Windows 7**, **node v8.11.1**, **npm v4.1.2**.

Per instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base

I have installed install-peerdeps via:

```
npm install -g install-peerdeps
```

It looks like it’s version 1.6.0.

When I then run:

```
install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb-base
```

I get the following error:

```
'install-peerdeps' is not recognized as an internal or external
command, operable program or batch file.
```

My NODE_PATH variable is set to:

```
%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

If I do a `npm root -g` I get:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can get install-peerdeps working?

Comment: npm paths have really bad issues. Try checking both of those physical paths, and running it directly from the node_modules where it installed in package manager console.

Comment: Do you think that be this file?  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\install-peerdeps\lib\install-peerdeps.js ? There's also a cli.js in lib.

Comment: It looks like perhaps it's the cli.js file?  From their package.json fie: "bin": {
    "install-peerdeps": "lib/cli.js"
  },

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `install-peerdeps` globally installed?

Try installing `install-peerdeps` the package as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nathanhleung/install-peerdeps) and try again.

```
# If you're using npm
npm install -g install-peerdeps

# If you're using yarn
yarn add install-peerdeps -g
```

I had the same error on the OSX and I got it solved after I installed the `install-peerdeps` package. I hope it solves the error for windows as well.